# Symfony - no route found

Tags: php, symfony

No route found for "GET /hello.html"

This is the error I get when I try to access `http://localhost/project/web/app_dev.php/hello.html`

DefaultController:

```
<?php
/**
 * @Route("/hello.html")
 * @Template()
 */
public function indexAction()
{
    return array();
}
?>
```

Routing.yml:

```
MyHelloworldBundle:
    resource: "@MyHelloworldBundle/Controller/"
    type:     annotation
    prefix:   /
```

AppKernel.php:

```
class AppKernel extends Kernel
{
    public function registerBundles()
    {
        $bundles = array(
            new Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\FrameworkBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\SecurityBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\TwigBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\MonologBundle\MonologBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\SwiftmailerBundle\SwiftmailerBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\AsseticBundle\AsseticBundle(),
            new Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\DoctrineBundle(),
            new Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\SensioFrameworkExtraBundle(),
            new JMS\AopBundle\JMSAopBundle(),
            new JMS\DiExtraBundle\JMSDiExtraBundle($this),
            new JMS\SecurityExtraBundle\JMSSecurityExtraBundle(),
            new My\HelloworldBundle\MyHelloworldBundle(),
        );

        if (in_array($this->getEnvironment(), array('dev', 'test'))) {
            $bundles[] = new Symfony\Bundle\WebProfilerBundle\WebProfilerBundle();
            $bundles[] = new Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\SensioDistributionBundle();
            $bundles[] = new Sensio\Bundle\GeneratorBundle\SensioGeneratorBundle();
        }

        return $bundles;
    }

    public function registerContainerConfiguration(LoaderInterface $loader)
    {
        $loader->load(__DIR__.'/config/config_'.$this->getEnvironment().'.yml');
    }
}
```

The whole file structure seems to be ok, src/My/HelloworldBundle/...What's wrong?

The only thing I did as far is deleting acme demo - three parts of routing_dev.php, and the line from AppKernel.php.

Changing annotation in the controller to something else doesn't work either. The view file src/My/HelloworldBundle/Resources/views/Default/index.html.twig exists.

EDIT:

None of the routes matches when I execute the route:match command.

This is the error log: http://khernik.pl/asd.png
And the top part: http://khernik.pl/asdf.png

I now executed everything from the beginning, with symfony most default settings (with its own code added while creating a new bundle). The ONLY thing I did was deleting Acme line from AppKernel.php and three first blocks for acme from routing_dev.yml. Everything seems right.

Yet, still doesnt work.

EDIT 2 - FULL DEFAULT CONTROLLER:

```
<?php

namespace My\HelloworldBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Template;

class DefaultController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/hello/{name}")
     * @Template()
     */
    public function indexAction($name)
    {
        return array('name' => $name);
    }
}
```

Comment: have you put the right namespace at the top of your file, as it does not appear in your post.

Comment: namespace My\HelloworldBundle\Controller; - sure

Comment: What if you run [`php app/console router:debug`](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/routing.html#visualizing-debugging-routes)?

Comment: Displays OK in each line.

Comment: Can you post the result in your question? And run as well `php app/console router:match /hello.html`.

Comment: Tell me if I am wrong but your route is setup to be `/hello.html` and you call `/hello/abc` so it doesn't work. What if you change your route to `/hello` and you `/hello` in your browser?

Comment: Oh, sorry, the whole copy and paste thing...of course it's @Route("/hello/{name}") now, just as it is by default when creating a new bundle.

Comment: What's interesting is that the demo works well, when I click "hello world" hypherlink it displays everything perfectly.

Comment: One more thing to be sure, you have the line `use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;` on top of your controller right?

Comment: Oh, and the link without app_dev.php within shows 404 page if it helps something.

Comment: Yes I do have it ofc.

Comment: And if you remove the trailing slash in `resource: "@MyHelloworldBundle/Controller/"` to make it `resource: "@MyHelloworldBundle/Controller"`?

Comment: Same thing :/ Triple checked everything, still nothing...

Comment: And cleared the cache? (I am running out of solutions...)

Comment: even deleted the whole folder eventually

Comment: Crap, I guess it's time to post the thread on some symphony forum ;( Can u recommend any good one?

Comment: One last try, when you hit your `config.php` everything is fine?

Comment: That doesn't display any unusual red messages, just recommendations for installing intl and PHP Accelerator. I also haven't configured the database through that, don't know if it's necessary.

Comment: The DB is not necessary...try in the [google group](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!forum/symfony2) or on [irc](http://symfony.com/irc) and don't forget to post the solution if you find one! Sorry to not be able to help more... :)

Comment: Can you post your full controller file just in case?

Comment: I have never used `@Template` but does it make a difference if you put `@Template` instead of `@Template()`? (I guess no but...)

Comment: Nope. It must be something with routing yml files though...I have the one with resource/prefix in app/config, and I don't have any in src/ folder. Is this right?

Comment: As you are using @Route annotation then you should be ok.

Answer (score 0):

Try to indicate the `Template()` property in annotation of your `DemoController`

```
<?php
/**
 * @Route("/hello")
 * @Template('MyHelloworldBundle:Demo:hello.html')
 */
public function helloAction()
{
    return array();
}
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

Please add your ControllerName before hello.html

```
class DemoController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/hello.html")
     * @Template()
     */
    public function indexAction()
    {
        return array();
    }
```

Like, To access this: call this url below:

```
http://localhost/project/web/app_dev.php/demo/hello.html
```

Comment: Why would he need to put the ControllerName??